# Inconsistent Python Calculations

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

I am writing a function to calculate the chi-squared statistic of a piece of ciphertext to determine the most likely key for a caesar cipher.

To calculate the chi-squared statistic I calculate the relative frequencies of each english character using a file from [PracticalCryptography.com](http://practicalcryptography.com/cryptanalysis/letter-frequencies-various-languages/english-letter-frequencies/) and store these in a dictionary, I then count the occurences of each english letter, ignoring spaces and punctuation, in the string `Ciphertext` and store these in a dictionary and then calculate the Chi-Squared statistic using the equation from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test#Example_chi-squared_test_for_categorical_data) and [PracticalCryptograhy.com](http://practicalcryptography.com/cryptanalysis/text-characterisation/chi-squared-statistic/).

Code:

```
def ChiSquared(Ciphertext):
    ALPHABET = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

    ExpOccurences = {}
    with open('english_monograms.txt', 'r') as File:
        for Line in File:
            Key, Count = Line.split(' ')
            ExpOccurences[Key] = int(Count)

    for Key, Count in ExpOccurences.items():
        ExpOccurences[Key] = Count / sum(ExpOccurences.values())

    ActOccurences = {}
    for Char in Ciphertext.upper():
        if Char in ALPHABET:
            if Char in ActOccurences.keys():
                ActOccurences[Char] += 1
            else:
                ActOccurences[Char] = 1

    Score = 0.0
    for Char in ActOccurences.keys():
        Score += (ActOccurences[Char] - (ExpOccurences[Char] * len(Ciphertext))) ** 2 / (ExpOccurences[Char])

    return Score
```

My issue is that each time I call the function with the same string, I get a different `Score`. Why does this happen and how can I prevent/fix it? Should I hard-code the frequencies instead? Is it due to an underflow error when calculating the relative frequencies?

Example of Inconsistency:

```
>>> ChiSquared('HELLO WORLD')
139.3055836714786
>>>
>>> ChiSquared('HELLO WORLD')
140.48594498993816
>>> 
>>> ChiSquared('HELLO WORLD')
132.3702317119948
>>>
>>> ChiSquared('HELLO WORLD')
65.840138355439
>>>
>>> ChiSquared('HELLO WORLD')
129.22608450306808
>>>
```

Comment: Your code is very hard to read. For function and variable names, if you're going to use camel case, start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: You are modifying `ExpOccurances` while iterating over it, and the order of iteration will change from session to session due to hash randomization. Each time through the loop, `ExpOccurences.values()` will return a different sequence.

Comment: @chepner Thank you for your comment.  I have changed the code to record the sum of the dictionary values before the loop and it now produces the exact same result.